# play Mp3 Intent Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent

I have `callintent()` method in `MainActivity`:

```
public void callintent (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent (this, DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("string", "String Text");
    i.putExtra("img", R.drawable.icon);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

that method is set string and image for `DetailActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String string = i.getStringExtra("string");

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textview.setText(string);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getIntent().getIntExtra("img",0)));
}
```

i was successfuly display text and image in `DetailActivity` but now i want add mp3 file for play in `DetailActivity` where the file is set in `MainActivity`,

Please Help Me, Thank you

-- Edited --

i can play mp3 with add this in `MainActivity`

```
i.putExtra("selectedMp3",R.raw.file);
```

and add this in `DetailActivity`

```
int mp3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedMp3", 0);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, mp3);
mp.start();
```

but sound still playing when backpress or go to homescreen,
how can i stop sound when backpress or go to homescreen,

Comment: use  `mp.stop(); `  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to play an audio or mp3 file.

1. Using Intents and playing them outside the app:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent();  
   i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "audio/*");  
   startActivity(i);
   ```

If you use this method and if the android SDK version for build Gradle is greater than 23 u must use the `FileProvider` to give permission to access file outside the application. The flag and action will be like below:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file), "audio/*");
```

2. Using Media Player and playing them with in the app and add the relevant permission in the manifest:

   MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
   mPlayer.start();

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Put your mp3 file in `raw` folder

Step 2 : Call below `MediaPlayer` code in `DetailActivity`

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
mPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent in = new Intent();  
in.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(File_Path);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(in);
```